# Azure Pipelines - Parallel steps (YAML)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up my Azure Devops Pipelines, and have a build that requires some fairly lengthy setup steps to run.  These need to run before other tasks, which can be run in parallel.

However, I can only see this being done by specifying jobs, which would require to do these lengthy steps each time.  Ie:

```
jobs:
  - job: Run1
     steps:
       - task: Long running setup task
       - task: Run taskA
  - job: Run2
       - task: Long running setup task
       - task: Run taskB
```

Is there a way to have this long running task run, and have task A/B depend on that environment without running them sequentially? Ideally it'd be something like:

```
jobs:
  - job: Run1
    steps:
      - task: Long running setup
      - task: Parallel: taskA
      - task: Parallel: taskB
```

Or have the previous jobs take a container/image snapshot and reuse if that's possible?

Comment: I have the same question. I have a build task and a subsequent validation task. The validation task requires install of json lint. Running the build and json lint install in parallel would be quicker.

Comment: Any update on this one?

Answer (score 19):

Short answer, you can't.

Tasks within a job cannot run in parallel as they run on the same agent and the environments can't be "snapshotted" by Azure Devops to be re-utilized by other jobs in parallel later. But jobs can run in parallel as they can be scheduled on different agents, so setup will run twice but in parallel. So there is a trade-off between time and resource usage which you will need to decide on based on your requirements.

There is another solution though, based on how much you would like to invest in this:

If your "setup" doesn't change that often and you are willing to host your own agents. Then you could run a separate "setup + agent" build which creates a docker image of your agents, pushes it out to your azure container registry and then deploys this image to your self-hosted agents (Azure Kubernetes Service) cluster. Then Task A and Task B can easily run in parallel with the assumption that the environment they are running in (agent + setup docker image) is always ready. This is exactly my setup.

See : [Azure DevOps Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops)

Comment: See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365659/ability-to-run-tasks-in-parallel.html .

Sadly no sign of it on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline .

Answer (score 2):

An update to this - a docker image as suggested by @dparker, while it is probably a better way, was a bit OTT for myself.  Instead I used a pipeline artifact to cache some build / setup files.  And then each other job was made dependent on this setup job.

This obviously doesn't sound great, but it works fine to get the performance optimizations I was after.

Eg Job1 would include this:

```
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
    inputs:
      artifactName: 'Setup-Build'
      targetPath: '$(buildDir)'
```

And Job2 to X would download this as an artifact:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Download Setup'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(buildDir)'
      artifactName: 'Setup-Build'
```

Additionally there is the option to use caching, but this didn't quite fit in with my scenario.  I'd recommend you make a call between artifacts and caching:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops

Comment: Be aware of known issue about super slow cache speeds. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11864

Comment: @jamesdill , why do you think that the artifacts dependency doesn't sound great? As for me this looks like the best possible solution for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Well I didn't say it doesn't sound great,  just that I see creating a once off docker image being a lot more overhead,  where, for me, caching did the same thing.